# Can I use av_write_frame() instead of av_interleaved_write_frame()?

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, libavformat

I'm writing an AV muxer DirectShow Filter on Windows platform using ffmpeg, it muxes video & audio streams into mp4/ts/flv file, or rtsp/rtmp/udp stream, I confirm that the dts of video/audio stream is increased orderly so dts reorder is no needed, so can I use `av_write_frame()` instead of `av_interleaved_write_frame()`? `av_write_frame()` writes packet to muxer directly, `av_interleaved_write_frame()` will make a copy of packet if it is not reference-counted, so I prefer to use `av_write_frame()` because I think it should be more efficient (no copying or buffering), is my thinking correct? Can I use `av_write_frame()`?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. As the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavf__encoding.html#gaa85cc1774f18f306cd20a40fc50d0b36) for `av_write_frame()` states:

> This function passes the packet directly to the muxer, without any
>   buffering or reordering. The caller is responsible for correctly
>   interleaving the packets if the format requires it. Callers that want
>   libavformat to handle the interleaving should call
>   av_interleaved_write_frame() instead of this function.